# How to handle Image carousel in protractor which are moving with time interval of 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

```
<div class="carousel ng-isolate-scope" ng-mouseleave="play()" ng-mouseenter="pause()" no-wrap="false" interval="3000">
<ol class="carousel-indicators" ng-show="slides().length > 1"/>
<div class="carousel-inner" ng-transclude="">
    <div class="item text-center ng-isolate-scope next left" ng-transclude="" ng-class="{ 'active': leaving || (active && !entering), 'prev': (next || active) && direction=='prev', 'next': (next || active) && direction=='next', 'right': direction=='prev', 'left': direction=='next' }">
        <div class="col-md-10 text-center center-img ng-scope">
            <img width="800px" height="480px" alt="neustar" src="app/images/Landing.png">
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="item text-center ng-isolate-scope active left" ng-transclude="" ng-class="{ 'active': leaving || (active && !entering), 'prev': (next || active) && direction=='prev', 'next': (next || active) && direction=='next', 'right': direction=='prev', 'left': direction=='next' }">
            <div class="col-md-10 text-center center ng-scope" style="height: 500px;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" ng-show="slides().length > 1" ng-click="prev()"/>
        <a class="right carousel-control" ng-show="slides().length > 1" ng-click="next()"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is to move the mouse control over carousel .so that the image carousel stop moving/rotating

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using "browser.wait" with "protractor.expectedCondition.visibiltyOf" and then performing the action you want.

Without more context of the problem and expectations, I can't be more specific.

Comment: i have tried using mousemove method 
browser.executeScript('$("div.carousel.ng-isolate-scope").mousemove();'); browser.sleep(1000);

Comment: @ Chuck Brown 
i have tried using mousemove method to handle that carousel
browser.executeScript('$("div.carousel.ng-isolate-scope").mousemove();'); browser.sleep(1000);
but it didn't worked for me.